# Querying a vector of struct in Rust

Tags: string, vector, struct, filter, rust

I am having a struct as below. I need to filter data from this struct for 2 scenario's

```
pub struct Access {
    role: String,
    users: Vec<String>,
}

pub struct Department_Access {
    department: String,
    department_id: String,
    access: Vec<Access>,
}
```

**Scenario 1**

I am getting dept id and user (single user) as input which i should filter all departments respective user contains access and return whole data to UI. i tried this as below and its throwing error as "*expected `bool`, found `core::iter::adapters::Filter<IntoIter, fn(&Access) -> bool>*". How to do this in efficient way ?

```
  let access_data = get_access_data();
    let user_access: Vec<ent::Department_Access> = access_data
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|r| r.department_id == dept_id)
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|a| a.access.into_iter().filter(|b| b.members.contains(user)))
        .collect();
```

**Scenario 2**

In another functionality, i am receiving `user` and `department` alone as a param which should query in above struct and return all department_id he had access to, which i struggling to do the basic form of query, Need your help in querying the same as well! Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please limit posts to a *single* question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [`any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any):

```rust
    let user_access: Vec<Department_Access> = access_data
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|r| r.department_id == dept_id)
        .filter(|a| a.access.iter().any(|b| b.users.contains(&user)))
        .collect();
```

Also keep in mind that `into_iter` consumes the value; you want to use `iter()` only in a `filter`.